# iOS cannot change frame of UIButton

Tags: ios, uibutton, storyboard

I am currently stuck with a very weird problem. I am using iOS 6 and Xcode 4.5. I have a storyboard with a `UIViewController` and a `UIButton` in it. I made a weak `UIButton` outlet to my .h file.

In the .m file I want to change the frame of the button but nothing happens. Yet I have an `UIImageView` created and connected the same way as the `UIButton` but I can change the `UIImageView`'s frame without any problems.

When I do this:

```
NSLog(@"%@", button)
```

I get this output:

```
<UIButton: 0xa185a40; frame = (191 330; 73 44); opaque = NO; autoresize = TM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0xa185640>>
```

And these are the relevant parts of my code:

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
    [self addStampGrid];
}

-(void)addStampGrid {

    // ...

    [_button setFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,10,10)];
}
```

Comment: How'bout showing some more context? http://sscce.org

Comment: Before you try to set the frame, try `NSLog("%@", button);` and make sure that it is not nil.  I suspect that the outlet is not setup correctly.

Comment: hmmm `button` in NSLog and `_button` in setFrame

Comment: my fault.. made a mistake in the update. in my code i used "_" everywhere.

Comment: anyway i will add the button programmatically, although it is much more work to add all the properties ... -.-

Answer (score 23):

I had the same weird problem using XCode 4.5 and iOS 6 as deployment target. I am not using story board though.
I managed to solve it by disabling the option "Use Autolayout" in the Interface Builder. (In the file inspector->Interface builder document.

Hope this helps

Comment: This seems like a quick hack and bad idea. It would be better to just change the constraints with @IBOutlets and modify the button.layer.frame.

Answer (score 11):

You can change frame of your UIButton by changing layer's frame of UIButton

```
 [self.button.layer setFrame:]
```

import QuartzCore framework in your class header before using this.
This will work with auto layout also.

Comment: Up-voted, it worked for me. I don't know why this question has been Down-voted before.

Answer (score 8):

You can use this

```
[_button setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];
```

after this you can set frame of your button.
It may give some warnings in log about constraints, as this property override constraints you gave in autolayout.

Answer (score 6):

Remove the view from the superview and after setting frame add this view again as a subview. Hope this will work fine...

Comment: This did work for me, without requiring that I turn off "Use Autolayout" entirely. So I can have a mix of auto layout and manual calculation when expedient. +1!

Answer (score 1):

//Remove the view from the superview

```
UIView *view = yourButton.superview;
[yourButton removeFromSuperview];
```

//change frame of UIButton

```
CGRect bounds = view.bounds;
yourButton.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(bounds), CGRectGetMidY(bounds));
```

//add this view again as a subview

```
[view addSubview:yourButton];
```