# Can't set size of UIButton frame with auto layout enabled

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, autolayout, frame

I really tried hard to solve this apparently simple problem by myself, but I couldn't fix it yet!

So here's the deal:

I am using a storyboard with auto layout enabled.
But because of to many objects in one of my views, I decided to implement the

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
                                         duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

method for this view controller and set the frames for the views explicit like so:

```
self.startStopBtn.frame = CGRectMake(10, 223.5, 300, 30);
```

And it works fine as long as I keep the size of this `UIButton` object the same (as in the storyboard) and only change its origin. As soon as I change the size the button is gone!

Finally enough I can change the frames of the labels, views and image views without any problems in the same method in the exact same way.

I really would appreciate your help!
Hopefully somebody can guide me in the right direction.

Comment: This maybe duplicated with:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769906/ios-cannot-change-frame-of-uibutton

Answer (score 2):

if you are using autolayout you should not manimulate `UIView` frame. You should modify `NSLayoutConstaints` to change something in view from code.

Comment: Okay, but this means I have to create outlets to all constraints I want to change. And why can I change the frames of all the other objects? It's just the UIButton that I can't change!

Comment: It is not completely true, because the biggest adventitious of autolayout are opportunity to setup relation between objects, so you should setup a view in the way that you dose not need all constraints per subview or setup autolayout to auto expand a subview depends on content, this way you does not need any constraints in your code.

Comment: Okay! I will give it another try! I will spend some time trying to set up auto layout in my storyboard, so that I don't need to manipulate any constraints from my code. Thank you very much for your response!