# How to change button size xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

My code to change button size when press:

```
  [_btnClick setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //  oldPosition =CGPointMake(sender.bounds.origin.x, sender.bounds.origin.y);
  _btnClick.frame = CGRectMake(oldPosition.x+20  , oldPosition.y+10, 500, 500);
```

but when i press button, just image change and button size not change to new size.

How i fix it. Thank' for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[In a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769906/ios-cannot-change-frame-of-uibutton), an explanation is provided. The only thing that seems valid would be to do what the top answer says. **Disable Auto layout**